# FormData with OData Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've successfully made upload/download calls with the vanilla web api, but now I am trying to consolidate my logic on `ODataController`s, so making these upload/download calls part of the same controller that returns the list of files.

To do this I made an action:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IEnumerable<FileComponent>> Upload()
{
    try
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileComponent>>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, t.Exception));
                }

                var fileComponents = new List<FileComponent>();
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    string filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                    var filepath = root + filename;
                    if (File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        // If previous entry exists, delete
                        File.Delete(filepath);
                    }

                    // The file is saved with a random GUID for name. Can rename it here.
                    string guidFilepath = file.LocalFileName;
                    File.Move(guidFilepath, filepath);

                    fileComponents.Add(new FileComponent()
                    {
                        Name = filename,
                        Size = new FileInfo(filepath).Length
                    });
                }
                return fileComponents;
            });
    }
    finally
    {
        log.Info("Exiting Post");
    }
}
```

However it never works. It always arrives with no FormData populating in the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`, and the exception is caught and returned as 'Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.'.

Any ideas? I'm assuming OData is cleaning it.

Comment: Hey @Tim, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Nope. :( Given up on this atm, OData wasn't designed for transfer of data that's not predefined objects with properties.

Comment: I was able to come with an ad-hock solution for this, by creating a custom MediaTypeFormatter to handle 'multipart/form-data'. I'll share the solution when after creating a blog post for it

Comment: Cool! Looking forward to it.

Comment: @CoffeeCode How did it go with the blog post?